# Source for Yirmiyahu abolishing the counting of Nisan

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, months, yosef-albo, jeremiah

The following is found in [Sefer HaIkarrim](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaIkkarim%2C_Maamar_3.19.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> ומה ששמעו ישראל לירמיה לבטל מנין החדשים מניסן כמו שאמרנו, אפשר שעשו כן משום דאשכוח קרא ודרוש
>
> The reason the Israelites obeyed Jeremiah and abolished counting the months from Nisan, as we have seen, is perhaps because they based their action upon the interpretation of a biblical verse

What is meant by "Jeremiah abolished counting the months from Nisan"? When did he do this? And what source does Albo get this from?

Answer (score 1):

He is referring to [what he wrote earlier](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_HaIkkarim%2C_Maamar_3.16?vhe=Sefer_Ha-%27ikkarim&lang=bi) in the piece, that the returnees from the Babylonian exile abolished the numbering of months starting from Nissan, as was the practice until then, and instead used the Assyrian names for each month.

This was done based on Jeremiah's prophecy that the miracle of the return from Babylon would eclipse that of the exodus from Egypt.

---

Sefer HaIkkarim 3:16:

> וכן עשו דבר אחר זכר לגאולה השנית, והוא שהניחו מלמנות מנין החדשים מניסן כמו שהיו רגילין למנות זכר ליציאת מצרים, וחזרו למנות מנין אחר לחדשים, וזהו שאמרו רבותינו ז״ל שמות החדשים עלו עמהם מאשור, כלומר שהיו מונין החדשים בשמותם תשרי מרחשון כסליו כמו שהיו מונין אותם באשור זכר לגאולה השנית ולא שני שלישי רביעי כאשר בתחלה, וכן כתב הרמב״ן ז״ל בפרשת בא אל פרעה. ונראה מזה כי הם הבינו שצווי מנין החדשים היה זמניי, רוצה לומר כל עוד שתתמיד הגאולה ההיא, אבל אחר שגלו שנית ונגאלו משם ונצטוו על ידי ירמיה לא יאמר עוד חי ה׳ אשר העלה את בני ישראל מארץ מצרים כי אם חי ה׳ אשר העלה ואשר הביא את זרע בית ישראל מארץ צפון וגו׳, ראו להניח המנין הראשון שהיה זכר ליציאת מצרים וחזרו למנות מנין אחר מתשרי לשנות העולם, והשאירו שמות החדשים שעלו עמהם מאשור זכר לגאולה השנית, כי הבינו שצווי מנין החדשים מניסן היה זמניי ולא צווי נצחי אף על פי שלא נזכר בו זמן.
>
> And they also did another thing in memory of the second deliverance, namely they ceased counting the months from Nisan, as they had been accustomed to do in memory of the Exodus from Egypt, and adopted another method of counting. This is what our Rabbis mean when they say, “The names of the months came with them from Assyria.” That is to say, they counted the months by name, Tishri, Marheshvan, Kislev, as they did in Assyria, in memory of the second deliverance, and not second, third, fourth, as they did before. This is also the explanation of Nahmanides in his commentary on section “Bo.”
>
> It seems from this, then, that they understood the pentateuchal commandment concerning the numbering of the months to be temporary, i. e. as long as that deliverance lasted. But after they were exiled a second time and were delivered again, and were told by Jeremiah, “They shall no more say: ‘As the Lord liveth, that brought up the children of Israel out of the land of Egypt;’ but: ‘As the Lord liveth, that brought up and that led the seed of the house of Israel out of the north country’ …,” they thought that it was proper to give up the first mode of counting which was in memory of the Exodus from Egypt, and adopted a different one, beginning with Tishri, when they counted the years of the world. And they also retained the names of the months which they brought with them from Assyria, in memory of the second deliverance, for they understood that the commandment in the Pentateuch to count the months from Nisan was temporary and not perpetual, though there is no mention of time.